# Save contents of many csv without exceeding time limit

Tags: php, csv

My site is hosted on a shared hosting I hired from Hostgator. But `set_time_limit` is only `30` and you can not change the limit because it is shared hosting. Their rule.

So I split my `csv` file which has about `5.500` records in 8 `csv` files.

My question, is there any way to run the 8 files in sequence in a single `function` without exceeding the `time_limit` of the server?

Example:

```
$lines = file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/lines1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
    //here is some code for save you content line
}
```

Comment: call it in the background command line scripts have no time limit `exec("php csv_import.php > /dev/null &"); `

Comment: The real question is: What are you doing with those lines? Reading 5000 Lines alone is not going to reach the timelimit by any means - perhaps there is room for improvement in the processing.

Comment: Agree with @ccKep, reading 5500 records from one file shouldn't take more than 1-2 seconds at most. Still, if you're accessing the script from a browser you could have it accept a parameter for the file number and redirect to the next one when it's done. E.g. `script.php?file=1` reads `lines1.csv` then redirects to `script.php?file=2` and so on, until all files are read.

Comment: Thanks @tim but it really is the first time I see something from background command,  I was a bit confused about the code

Comment: @rickdenhaan Actually the time to run is a lot, because of the various manipulations of data it has in function

Comment: @rickdenhaan "and redirect to the next one when it's done" I still can not visualize how I could do this

Comment: @Gislef The explanation would be too big to fit in a comment, so I've provided an example in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon my comment about setting up a parameter and redirecting, here's a barebones example.

In its bare essentials, the script could look something like this:

```
// require the ?file= parameter to exist
if (empty($_GET['file'])) {
    echo 'No file-parameter provided.';
    exit();
}

$file = $_GET['file'];

// build the full path to the file
$filename = get_template_directory_uri() . '/lines' . $file . '.csv';

// make sure the file exists, this will make sure the script stops
// when the last file has been processed
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    echo 'File ' . $file . ' does not exist. Processing may be complete.';
    exit();
}

// read and process the file
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
    // process this line
}

// build the URL to the next file
$next_script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?file=' . ($file + 1);

// set a HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect header and tell the browser
// where to go
http_response_code(307);
header('Location: ' . $next_script);
exit();
```

Now you can start your import process by going to `http://example.com/script.php?file=1`.

Note that for redirection with the `header()` function to work, you cannot output anything first. `header()` sets a HTTP response header, which must be sent to the browser before the response body (like HTML, Javascript, etc.).

If you can't guarantee that, an alternative solution is to use a javascript redirect:

```
// build the URL to the next file
$next_script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?file=' . ($file + 1);

// redirect using javascript
echo '<script>window.location.href = "' . $next_script . '";</script>';
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the file is `/public_html/example.com/wp-content/themes/thema/inc/theme-options.php` The url on the admin page is:  `https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=options_theme`  I'm a bit confused as to insert the variable in the url, because the submit button is within the wordpress theme options

Comment: @Gislef Ah. I'm afraid I can't help you with that, I have always managed to stay far away from Wordpress. If you edit your question and add the [tag:wordpress] tag, that might get someone's attention.